# Terraform 0.12 syntax to convert map of locals into list output

Tags: terraform

I have a Terraform module that having a map of locals like this...

```
locals {
  prod_cidrs = {
    xxx = "XX.XX.XX.XX/DV"
    yyy = "YY.YY.YY.YY/DV"
    zzz = "ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ/DV"
  }
  dev_cidrs = {
    xxx = "XX.XX.XX.XX/PD"
    yyy = "YY.YY.YY.YY/PD"
    zzz = "ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ/PD"
  }
}
```

...provide some outputs like...

```
output "prod_cidrs" {
  value = local.prod_cidrs
}

output "dev_cidrs" {
  value = local.dev_cidrs
}
```

so consumers can fetch `module.my_module.dev_cidrs.xxx` (that will be or `"XX.XX.XX.XX/DV"`) or `module.my_module.prod_cidrs.yyy` (that will be or `"YY.YY.YY.YY/PD"`) among the rest of combinations.

Now I want to provide an additional `output` that gives my consumer the ability of fetching all prod or dev CIDRs as a list at once, so the result will be, for `prod_cidrs` for example:

`["XX.XX.XX.XX/PD", "YY.YY.YY.YY/PD", "ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ/PD"]`

How can I achieve this without modifying the my current `locals`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `module.my_module.dev_cidrs` output directly you will see that it's a map which is what allows you to select `module.my_module.dev_cidrs.xxx` to use the `xxx` key and return its value.

If you want the list of values of `prod_cidrs` then you can just use the [`values` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/values.html).

The callers of your module could do this themselves like this:

```
module "foo" {
  source = "./module"
}

output "dev_x" {
  value = module.foo.dev_cidrs.xxx
}

output "all_prod_map" {
  value = module.foo.prod_cidrs
}

output "all_prod_list" {
  value = values(module.foo.prod_cidrs)
}
```

Or you could add an extra output to your module:

```
locals {
  prod_cidrs = {
    xxx = "XX.XX.XX.XX/DV"
    yyy = "YY.YY.YY.YY/DV"
    zzz = "ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ/DV"
  }
  dev_cidrs = {
    xxx = "XX.XX.XX.XX/PD"
    yyy = "YY.YY.YY.YY/PD"
    zzz = "ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ/PD"
  }
}

output "prod_cidrs" {
  value = local.prod_cidrs
}

output "dev_cidrs" {
  value = local.dev_cidrs
}

output "all_prod_cidrs" {
  value = values(local.prod_cidrs)
}
```

and they can then use it as `module.foo.all_prod_cidrs`.